# live form results using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to provide a message below the fields of a form.  The message will depend on what is entered in both fields.

How would I go about making it so it calculates in real time using both the fields and passing it through a calculation?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6qSeH/

I am using this to get the document values

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input-mini");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input-mini2");
```

and this at the end to run the function

```
yearCalculator();
```

Comment: You could use the **setInterval()** function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many missing pieces in your code.

Firstly you have written code **entirely using javascript** and trying to **use jQuery syntax.** So how would you expect it to work.

```
jQuery to set HTML     ---   msg.html(value);
javascriptto set HTML  ---   msg.html = value;
```

Second When you are checking for Not a Number

It is supposed to look like

**val1 === NaN   // It is not a string**
Also this will never work as  **NaN  is never equal to NaN**

Use `isNaN()` method instead

Third

```
<div class="message"></div>
```

supposed to be

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Next you need to assign events to your input. Otherwise it would only work when the page loads for the first time..

```
input1.addEventListener('change', yearCalculator);
input2.addEventListener('change', yearCalculator);
```

Otherwise it will only work the first time your script loads.

**Cleaned up code**

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input-mini");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input-mini2");
var msg = document.getElementById('message');

input1.addEventListener('change', yearCalculator);
input2.addEventListener('change', yearCalculator);

function yearCalculator() {
   var yearOne = input1.value;
    var yearTwo = input2.value;
    val1 = parseInt(yearOne);
    val2 = parseInt(yearTwo);
    if (isNaN(val1) || isNaN(val2)) {
        msg.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid year !!";
        return;
    }
    var value1 = yearOne - yearTwo + 18;

    if (yearOne == yearTwo) {
        msg.innerHTML = "Both years are the same";
    }

    if (yearOne < yearTwo) {
        if (yearTwo < value1) {
            msg.innerHTML = "This is a good result";
        } else if (yearTwo > value1) {
            msg.innerHTML = "This is a bad result";
        } else {
            msg.innerHTML  = "This is neither good or bad";
        }
    }
    else {
      msg.innerHTML ="Year 1 is greater than Year 2";  
    }
};
yearCalculator();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6qSeH/1/)**

Comment: Thankyou for the concise explanation.

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles .. Glad to have helped.. It is not the most optimized code . but you can take a stab at it

Answer (score 1):

You can use  onchange="yearCalculator()" in  both input fileds

Answer (score 0):

First change the `class='message'` to `id='message'`. Then try this code:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input-mini");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input-mini2");
var yearOne = input1.value;
var yearTwo = input2.value;
var msg = document.getElementById('message');

function yearCalculator(value1, value2) {
     msg.innerHTML='';
    val1 = parseInt(value1);
    val2 = parseInt(value2);
    if (val1 === "NAN" || val2 === "NAN") return;


    var value1 = val1 - val2 + 18;

    if (val1 == val2) {
        msg.innerHTML="Both years are the same";
    }

    if (val1 < val2) {
        if (val2 < value1) {
            msg.innerHTML = "This is a good result";
        } else if (val2 > value1) {
            msg.innerHTML = "This is a bad result";
        } else {
            msg.innerHTML = "This is neither good or bad";
        }
    }
};
yearCalculator(yearOne,yearTwo);
input1.onkeyup=function() {
     yearCalculator(this.value,document.getElementById("input-mini2").value);
};
input2.onkeyup=function() {
     yearCalculator(document.getElementById("input-mini").value,this.value);
};
```